# Apache Ignite: RDBMS, Failed to instantiate Spring XML application context

Tags: xml, spring, spring-boot, ignite

This is my first time using Apache Ignite and I am just messing around with the given example configuration files in the binary folder to get a feel of things.

My objective is to load data from an existing database into cache. The first and *only* step I've taken right now is to create my own XML file by following the [Apache Ignite doc for external storage](https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/persistence/external-storage#cachejdbcblobstore). However, I received an error after running the script `bash ignite.sh [file path]`.

**XML File (square bracketed database URL, user, and password)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">
    <bean id="mysqlDataSource" class="com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource">
        <property name="URL" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@//[host]:[port]/[database]"/>
        <property name="user" value="[user]"/>
        <property name="password" value="[password]"/>
    </bean>
    <bean id="ignite.cfg" class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.IgniteConfiguration">
        <property name="cacheConfiguration">
            <list>
                <!-- Partitioned cache example configuration (Atomic mode). -->
                <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.CacheConfiguration">
                    <property name="name" value="default"/>
                    <property name="cacheStoreFactory">
                        <bean class="org.apache.ignite.cache.store.jdbc.CacheJdbcBlobStoreFactory">
                        <property name="dataSourceBean" value = "mysqlDataSource" />
                        </bean>
                    </property>
                </bean>
            </list>
        </property>

        <!-- Explicitly configure TCP discovery SPI to provide list of initial nodes. -->
        <property name="discoverySpi">
            <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi">
                <property name="ipFinder">
                    <!-- Uncomment static IP finder to enable static-based discovery of initial nodes. -->
                    <!--<bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ipfinder.vm.TcpDiscoveryVmIpFinder">-->
                    <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ipfinder.multicast.TcpDiscoveryMulticastIpFinder">
                        <property name="addresses">
                            <list>
                                <!-- In distributed environment, replace with actual host IP address. -->
                                <value>127.0.0.1:47500..47509</value>
                            </list>
                        </property>
                    </bean>
                </property>
            </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

**Error**

```
    class org.apache.ignite.IgniteException: Failed to instantiate Spring XML application context (make sure all classes used in Spring configuration are present at CLASSPATH) [springUrl=file:/app/apache/apache-ignite-2.8.1-bin/examples/config/example-cache-blob-store.xml]
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.IgniteUtils.convertException(IgniteUtils.java:1067)
        at org.apache.ignite.Ignition.start(Ignition.java:349)
        at org.apache.ignite.startup.cmdline.CommandLineStartup.main(CommandLineStartup.java:300)
Caused by: class org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: Failed to instantiate Spring XML application context (make sure all classes used in Spring configuration are present at CLASSPATH) [springUrl=file:/app/apache/apache-ignite-2.8.1-bin/examples/config/example-cache-blob-store.xml]
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.spring.IgniteSpringHelperImpl.applicationContext(IgniteSpringHelperImpl.java:387)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.spring.IgniteSpringHelperImpl.loadConfigurations(IgniteSpringHelperImpl.java:104)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.spring.IgniteSpringHelperImpl.loadConfigurations(IgniteSpringHelperImpl.java:98)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.loadConfigurations(IgnitionEx.java:710)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start(IgnitionEx.java:911)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start(IgnitionEx.java:820)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start(IgnitionEx.java:690)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start(IgnitionEx.java:659)
        at org.apache.ignite.Ignition.start(Ignition.java:346)
        ... 1 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource] for bean with name 'mysqlDataSource' defined in URL [file:/app/apache/apache-ignite-2.8.1-bin/examples/config/example-cache-blob-store.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1397)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineTargetType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:638)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:607)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1496)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1018)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:737)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:542)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.spring.IgniteSpringHelperImpl.applicationContext(IgniteSpringHelperImpl.java:381)
        ... 9 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:251)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinition.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanDefinition.java:408)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doResolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1444)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1389)
        ... 17 more
Failed to start grid: Failed to instantiate Spring XML application context (make sure all classes used in Spring configuration are present at CLASSPATH) [springUrl=file:/app/apache/apache-ignite-2.8.1-bin/examples/config/example-cache-blob-store.xml]
Note! You may use 'USER_LIBS' environment variable to specify your classpath.
```

Answer (score 3):

You need put your MySQL JDBC driver where Ignite can find it. Simplest, as the error message says, it to add it to USER_LIBS, for example:

```
export USER_LIBS=/path/to/mysql-jdbc.jar
$IGNITE_HOME/bin/ignite.sh /path/to/ignite.xml
```

Comment: Hi! Your solution helped resolve the same problem I got with another XML file. However, I'm running into the same error for the XML file in question - would the error with this XML file have to deal with the CLASSPATH by any chance?

Comment: The error is `Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource`. I don't know exactly which JAR file you need to add, but that missing class is your problem.

Comment: Sorry that this is going to sound silly, but how and/or where would I need to add a JAR file -- right now all I have is an XML file that I'm passing to start a node

Comment: See my answer! Set (and export) USER_LIBS. The JAR file can be anywhere, you just have to tell Ignite where it is.